# Какая максимальная длина идентификаторов и можно ли ее изменить?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c

Использую версию 11g и хотел бы давать имена, длина которых - более чем 30 символов.
Мне известно, что максисмальная длина в 11g - только 30 символов:

```sql
create table tab (very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_LongColumnName number)
```

> ORA-00972: identifier is too long

- Возможно ли как-то изменить максимальную длину?
- Какая максимальная длина идентификаторов в версии 12c?

<sub>Свободный перевод [Change table/column/index names size in oracle 11g or 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18248318) от участника [@Sajad Bahmani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140934/sajad-bahmani)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/18248318

Answer (score 5):

Имена объектов БД [11g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223), а также в версии [12cR1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223), ограничены 30 байтами (в single-byte кодировке это эквивалентно 30 символам).

Можно ли это изменить? **Нет, не существует способа измененить это**, чтобы можно было пользоваться именами обьектов БД длиной более чем 30 байтов.

Ограничение в 30 байт было впервые снято во втором выпуске [12c ( 12cR2)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA), и если значение параметра инициаллизации `COMPATIBLE` установленно в `12.2` и выше, то макс. длина  идентификаторов может быть до 128 байт.

```sql
SQL> show parameters compat

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
compatible                           string      12.2.0

SQL> create table tab (very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_LongColumnName number);

Table TAB created.

SQL> declare very_very_very_very_very_very_very_very_LongVariableName number; begin null; end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18248529) от участника [@Nick Krasnov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997660/nick-krasnov)</sub>

Comment: они в Oracle Co. СТОЛЬКО лет держались и тут... :-D